# how to Get the Listview on select item in the spinner

Tags: android, android-listview, spinner

Actually i am developing an application which will implement all CURD operation.
My application consist of spinner,Listview,textbox.
Now what i want is, for updating operation , i need to get the values from the listview by selecting.

I don't know how to display the selected values(from Listview) in the Spinner.

Here is my spinner coding

```
sppriority = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_priority);
public void addNewTask(View view) {
HashMap<String, String> queryValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
queryValues.put("priority", sppriority.getSelectedItem().toString());

sppriority.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
int position, long id) {
// On selecting a spinner item
Task = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
});
```

and this is Listview on click code:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

lvpriority = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvpriority);
String vallvpriority = lvpriority.getText().toString();

Intent objIndent5 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),addinbox.class);
objIndent5.putExtra("lvpriority", vallvpriority);
}
```

This is how i used which is not working:

```
 **if(animalList.size()!=0) {

    sppriority.setText(animalList.get("priority"));
    }**

        public void editTask(View view) {
        HashMap<String, String> queryValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
        queryValues.put("priority", sppriority.getSelectedItem().toString());
        controller.updateTask(queryValues);
        }
```

Please Help me to get the selected item of listview to spinner.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline of a simple way:

```
1) Have a HashSet which is member of your activity, let us call it selectSet.
   //Initialize like this
   HashSet<String>selectSet=new HashSet<String>();

2) onItemClick of ListView, add item to selectSet.
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        lvpriority = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvpriority);
        String vallvpriority = lvpriority.getText().toString();
        selectSet.add(vallvpriority);
     }

3) Create ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, resource);
4) Iterate through the HashSet and add items to the spinnerAdapter
     for(String priority: selectSet){
        spinnerAdapter.add(priority);
     }
5) Set the spinnerAdapter to your spinner:
     spppriority.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick replay...I have tried as you suggest but i didn't get the selected value into the spinner

Comment: @Appdev Try checking selectSet.size() and spppriority.getAdapter().getCount(), see whether they are populated properly. Are you getting any error?

Comment: @ Kartik_Koro..If you don't mind can you please guide me to where to use the code which you suggested.Because i used at  item click listener but throws error at add by red underline ("The method add(String) is undefined for the type String
")

Comment: @Appdev just write it after you set adapter to the spinner, but you should not be getting the error of "undefined for type String", since `spppriority.getAdapter()` will return an `Object` of type `SpinnerAdapter` and `selectSet` is a `HashSet`. Are you sure you initialized the HashSet properly? I added edit with initialization of HashSet.

Comment: @ Kartik_Koro ..Once again thanks for showing interest to help me.If you Don't mind is it possible for you to provide any Examples.Sorry to trouble you.i'm very new to android so only